# jQuery .before with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just want to ask about `jQuery`. Can `jQuery` do this:

```
<h1 id="lorem-ipsum">Hello World!</h1>
```

to this:

```
<div id="lorem-ipsum"></div>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: Yes, jQuery can do that- or, rather, you can do that using jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this man: **working demo** Bit dynamic version: http://jsfiddle.net/QSdqM/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/GQzFU/

Hope it helps the cause `:)`

API: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

**code**

```
$('h1').replaceWith(function() {

   return '<div id="' + this.id + '"></div><h1>' + $(this).text() + '</h1>'

});
```

**OR**

```
$('h1').replaceWith('<div id="lorem-ipsum"></div><h1>Hello World!</h1>');


alert($('body').html());​
```

Comment: Could you make this a bit more generic?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDiv = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'lorem-ipsum');
$('h1#lorem-ipsum').removeAttr('id').before(myDiv);
```

Comment: You can replace `<div></div>` with `<div />`.

Comment: @Blender: or even `<div>`, or for better performance `document.createElement('div')`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var txt = $('#lorem-ipsum').text()
$('#lorem-ipsum')
    .after($('<h1/>').text(txt))
    .replaceWith('<div id="#lorem-ipsum"/>')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wnJQP/)